# How do I test whether a reference is NULL?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, reference

I want to check to see whether something is null, e.g.:

```
string xxx(const NotMyClass& obj) {
  if (obj == NULL) {
     //...
  }
}
```

But the compiler complains about this: there are 5 possible overloads of `==`.

So I tried this:

```
  if (obj == static_cast<NotMyClass>(NULL)) {
```

This crashes because `NotMyClass`'s `==` overload doesn't handle nulls.

edit:  for everyone tell me it can't be NULL, I'm certainly getting something NULL like in my debugger:

[image]

Comment: obj is a reference, not a pointer. You can't compare it to NULL.

Comment: C++ isn't C or Java. The answers here are good, but you might also benefit from reading up a little bit on pointers and references in C++.

Comment: I very much doubt you get a "crash" for that conditional.

Comment: @Tomalak  in my debugger, I see it trying to do obj.something() on that reference.  It certainly does crash it.

Comment: @deliciousirony: Not on that conditional, it doesn't. When you try to perform logic on `obj`, sure; but you already invoked Undefined Behaviour by obtaining that invalid reference in the first place.

Comment: The only sensible thing you could do to check for such a condition is `if(&obj==NULL)`, but it wouldn't make sense anyway, because if you are getting a "`NULL` reference" it means that you have a logic error in your application (you already dereferenced a `NULL` pointer to create such reference, so you are already in the land of undefined behavior). Because of this, the compiler could as well optimize away such a check, since it knows that `NULL` references do not exist (as it [routinely does](http://lwn.net/Articles/341773/) for `NULL` checks on pointers that have been already dereferenced).

Comment: That's a compilation error, not a crash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a well-formed C++ program, references are never `NULL` (more accurately, the address of an object to which you have a reference may never be `NULL`).

So not only is the answer "no, there's no way", a corollary is "this makes no sense".

---

Your statement regarding C makes no sense either, since C does not have references.

And as for Java, its "references" are more like C++ pointers in many ways, including this one.

Comparing such specific behaviours between different languages is something of a fool's errand.

---

If you need this "optional object" behaviour, then you're looking for pointers:

```
std::string xxx(const NotMyClass* ptr) {
  if (ptr == NULL)
     throw SomeException();

  const NotMyClass& ref = *ptr;
  /* ... */
}
```

But consider whether you really need this; a decent alternative might be `boost::optional` if you really do.

Comment: Somewhere further up the stack it is a pointer, and someone has converted it to a reference.  I get it as a reference.  And it is "NULL".

Comment: @deliciousirony: The program invokes UB the moment the person dereferenced that null pointer; anything after that is folly. You are seeing an implementation leak by pure chance (sort of)

Comment: @deliciousirony: And I think you mean `s/static/call stack/`

Answer (score 5):

What you're asking makes no sense. References in C++ can never be "null", since they can only ever be created by aliasing an existing object, and they cannot be rebound. Once a reference to `x`, always a reference to `x`.

(A reference may become "dangling" if the original object's lifetime ends before that of the reference, but that's a programming error and not a checkable runtime condition.)

Comment: not sure about that, for e.g.
```
int func(int& j) { return j;}

int i = 0;
int *p = &i;
p = nullptr;
func(*p);

```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to test this, as references in C++ can't be NULL.  *Pointers* can be NULL, but you're not using them here.

Answer (score 4):

As people have said references in C++ should never be null (NULL or nullptr), however it is still possible to get null references, especially if you do some evil casting. (A long time ago I did such a thing when I didn't know any better.)

To test if a reference is null (NULL or nullptr) convert it to a pointer and then test. So:

```
if (&obj == nullptr)
```

is what you are effectively looking for.

But now since you know how to do it, **don't**. Just assume that references can never be null and let the application crash if they are, because by then something else must have gone horribly wrong and the program should be terminated.

Comment: It is not possible in a well-formed program; your UB starts the moment you obtain a "reference" to an object that does not exist. Anything after that is folly.

Comment: `int& foo() { return (int&)*((int*)0); }` Will create a NULL reference, it will crash if you attempt to do pretty much anything with the return value except take a pointer.

Comment: No, there is no such thing as "a NULL reference". What you have is a program that's written in something that looks a bit like C++, that contains something that looks like a reference to an object that does not exist.

Comment: Yes, it's not valid, but it still means that it can be done and will compile. When run however it will crash at the first opportunity.

Answer (score 3):

As others said, well-defined code never has NULL references, so it's not your responsibility to test for them.

That doesn't strictly mean they aren't ever created in practice though (but hopefully in intermediate, rather than production code). It's possible in some compilers, though definitely not standard C++, to get a reference whose address is NULL:

```
int * p = NULL;
int & x = *p;
```

Often won't crash (yet), although by the C++ standard, it's nondeterministic behavior after the second line. This is a side-effect of references typically being implemented with pointers "behind the scenes." It will probably crash later down the line when someone uses x.

If you're trying to debug such a situation, you can test if the address of x is not NULL:

```
#include <cassert>
// ...
assert(&x != NULL);
```

Comment: +1 good answer, though it might be worth pointing out that the very phrase "references being `NULL`" is misleadingly wrong; it's the address of the object (albeit non-existent!) under reference that we're talking about.